# Does the event `invalid` only fire once?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I tried to hook into the [`invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event) event for numeric input (which is required), and while the `invalid` event fires right on loading the page (as all the cells are empty), it does not refire if one fills an input field and removes its content or inputs a letter instead of a number. But I could not find anything indicating that this would be its behaviour. But at the same time I can also not find an issue with my code. So I guess I am first asking what the desired behaviour is before I continue hunting for bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently rubber ducking is quite helpful:

The `invalid` event only fires on form *submission*, while the css `:invalid` styling is applied live on `input` events rather than only after `submission` events.

> If a form is submitted with an invalid value, the submittable elements are checked and, if an error is found, the invalid event will fire

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation:

> When a form is submitted, invalid events are fired at each form
> control that is invalid

So when a form is submitted, any input that doesn't adhere to it's constraints, will fire an `invalid` event.

Here the input is numeric and requires a min of 1. Setting it to 0 and submitting will trigger the `invalid` event.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').addEventListener('invalid', () => {
  console.log('invalid')
})
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" min="1" value="0">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```